# Roblox humanoid speed not increasing

Tags: lua, roblox

I have created an object with this code:

```
    script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(touched)
    local humanoid = touched.Parent:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        humanoid.Walkspeed = 32
    end
end)
```

This code should increase the humanoid walk speed from 16 to 32 when the humanoid touches it.
But the block doesn't increase the speed and Roblox Studios shows this error:

```
Walkspeed is not a valid member of Humanoid "Workspace.ZoopZappler1.Humanoid"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [wiki](https://roblox.fandom.com/wiki/WalkSpeed), you need `WalkSpeed` with a capital "S". Your code uses `Walkspeed`, with a lower-case "S".

Here's a fixed version:

```lua
local humanoid = touched.Parent:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
if humanoid then
    humanoid.WalkSpeed = 32
end
```